# Cannot access Nuget since last week

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

In Visual Studio, I can't see the Nuget packages or download new ones since last week. I am under a corporate proxy and nothing our computer's configuration has changed. Maybe it is a problem with our corporate Network but before that, I'd like to know what I can do.

I have set up my environment variables for my proxy (http_proxy and https_proxy) since day one and havent' changed anything.

I also realized that I can access this link in my browser: http://api.nuget.org/packages/entityframework.6.1.3.nupkg

but not this one: https://api.nuget.org/packages/entityframework.6.1.3.nupkg (The difference being the https). I get an infinite loading and then an ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error in my browser.

In Visual Studio, if I change the package source url to http, I can see the package listing (which I can't for the https) but I still get the following error when I try to install:

```
Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'EntityFramework' from source 'Nuget'.At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I'm out of clue here, let me know if anything is missing!

Answer (score 0):

NuGet reads the web proxy settings from NuGet.configure file, environment variables and current user’s Internet Options. In your situation, you just set up your environment variables.  But NuGet will find the proxy settings from NuGet.configure file first. So you need to set the proxy in NuGet.configure file which under path C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\NuGet”. Please add the proxy settings with below command.

> nuget.exe config -set http_proxy=your company proxy url

Please refer to:
http://skolima.blogspot.sg/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html